# webview remove Header and Footer in All web Pages

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Remove Header and Footer in All Pages in Webview android
Here my Code

when i open https://www.shopify.in/online in this link it's Still visible header and footer

```
url = "https://www.shopify.in/";
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
new MyAsynTask().execute();
        }

    private class MyAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document> {
        @Override
        protected Document doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Document document = null;
            try {
                document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                document.getElementsByClass("SiteNavContainer").remove();
                document.getElementsByClass("footer--main").remove();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return document;
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you that use Chrome Custom Tabs instead of Webview. It is very faster than the webview to load the url.

For More detail you can verify the below url:

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: i have checked this site. The header and footer is not removed from the site but it is responsive site so it is converted in slide menu icon.You can  open that link in mobile browser and unable to see header and footer

Answer (score 0):

After removing the header and footer you should load back the html onto the webview.
Try this,

```
webView.loadData(document.html(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Load the html on post execute of async thread.

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
            super.onPostExecute(document);
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, document.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", "");
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request); }});}

Comment: Here is my onPostExecute